# Eclipse AVR for arduino not uploading

Tags: avrdude

I recently read [this](http://horrorcoding.altervista.org/arduino-development-with-eclipse-a-step-by-step-tutorial-to-the-basic-setup/) post about setting up Eclipse for Arduino.  I Build the test project with no erros, but when I go to upload my test project it just hangs at 5%, with no error messages.

If I unplug the arduino-uno it cancels the upload, so I know it can see the arduino board. It is just not uploading. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong?

I don't know whats changed, but now it doesn't hang i just get a message after trying to upload:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Comment: Does the Arduino IDE upload successfully with the identical physical setup?